# Is there a simple way to track which process made a specific network call?

Tags: networking, process

I see in my reverse proxy logs that something on a server of mine is trying to connect to a service which name changed. It must have not be reconfigured after some names have indeed changed.

I see the source port of the process that makes the call but it of course is gone once the log is written (the call is over).

**Is there a simple way to track such a process?**

(my fallback solution will be to grep all the files on the system looking for the old name - it will work but I would be interested in a general solution)

Comment: No, there is no **simple** way to track such process. A first step could be to "mark" all packets with the PID/hostname. But even that is not simple.

Comment: You're looking for the process on a remote host that tried to connect to your host?

Comment: the (best imho) not so simple method to track such a process is by using `auditd` and related commands to record system calls. Exists at least on Solaris ([`auditd(1M)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/auditd-1m.html)) , FreeBSD ([`auditd(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=auditd&sektion=8)) and Linux ([`auditd(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd)). Implementations differ. Of course this has to be running on the system running the process. What OS is it?

Comment: @AndyDalton: it all runs on one system: there are several docker containers which are accessed via a reverse proxy (similar to traefik). I see in the logs that the target address is an old one. Something on the host server (the one who runs the docker engine) is making the calls.

Comment: @A.B: This is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: As it's quite complex I suggest you do research on auditd / auditctl. You can log all connect (64 bits arch) or socketcall (x86 32 bits arch, including 32 bits userland running on 64 bits kernel) system calls, and match the process with the SOCKADDR entry. This will capture for any socket type including unix sockets (ie: lot of noise).